# Define a dictionary with a name already stored as a string in the script

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to define a dictionary with a name that changes dynamically.
For example:

```
Dictname = 'Forrest'
Forrest = {}
```

The parameter Dictname is received from a textfile, the value forrest will be different every time the script runs

Comment: You can do:  `globals()[Dictname] = {}`

Comment: you can keep it in other dictionary - `data = dict()`, `data[Dictname] = {}` And then you can easily get something from dictionary - `print(data[Dictname])`. Or simply forget name `Forrest` and always use the same name.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). It's just not a good idea. It's awkward to do for a reason. When people want to do this, it's generally because of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I read the requirement correctly but here is something to try. I edited the answer after seeing the globals() comment.

Answer 1 is my original answer. However the next answer, answer 2, is more straightforward but is not significantly different from what has already been suggested in comments.

Answer 1.

```py
Dictionary = 'forrest'
exec('%s={}'%Dictionary)
exec('%s[\'mykey\']=123456'%Dictionary)
print(forrest)
```

Answer 2.

```py
Dictionary = 'forrest'
globals()[Dictionary]={}
globals()[Dictionary]['Mykey']=123456
print(globals()[Dictionary])
```